# Flask @login_required does not work on IE and Safari

Tags: python, internet-explorer, safari, flask, flask-login

I am trying to set up Flask-Login, but am having issues getting it to work when using Internet Explorer and Safari.

After logging in from the login page, users on those browsers are redirected back to the login page, and the log says the user is not logged in.

This works correctly on Firefox, Chrome, and Opera: users are redirected to the /top/ page.

Here is how I set up login_manager and the login view:

```
login_manager = LoginManager(app)

login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.login_message = u"Please log in to access this page."
#login_manager.refresh_view = "reauth"

#salt for hashing etc.
SALT = u""

# # Initialize extensions
# mail.init_app(app)
# db.init_app(app)
# login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    """
   Loads user from Database
   """
    try:
        user = User.objects(id=user_id).first()
    except Exception as inst:
        app.logger.error("Could not login user %s: %s" % (type(inst), type))
        return None

    if user is None:
        app.logger.error("No user found for %s" % user_id)
        return None

    return AppUser(user)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        app.logger.info("already logged in")
        return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for('top'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        e_mail = request.form['e_mail'].lower()
        password = request.form['password']
        app.logger.debug(password)
        app.logger.debug(e_mail)
        if e_mail is not None and password is not None:
            #get user from database
            try:
                start = time.time()
                users = User.objects(email=e_mail)
                user = users.first()
                end = time.time()

                app.logger.info("Getting user took %f.5 seconds." % (end - start))
            except Exception as inst:
                app.logger.error("Could not login user %s: %s" % (type(inst), type))
                raise abort(500)

            if user is None:
                app.logger.error("No user found for %s" % e_mail)
                flash('Username or password are not correct.', 'error')
            else:
                #check password
                m = hashlib.sha256()
                m.update(password.encode("UTF-8"))
                m.update(SALT.encode("UTF-8"))

                if m.hexdigest() == user.password:
                    app.logger.debug("Login %s" % e_mail)
                    login_user(AppUser(user))
                    app.logger.error("Args: %s" % request.args.get("next"))
                    return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for('top'))
                else:
                    flash('Username or password are not correct.', 'error')

    app.logger.error("not logged in")
    return render_template('login.html')
```

How can I make this work correctly in all browsers?

Comment: what I don't really see in your code is where you are restricting access. I am looking for the decorator which says `@login_required`. I'm also not sure if you have to do `AppUser(user)` as you seem to fetch it from the database using an ORM like SQLAlchemy.
I am not sure that `raise abort(500)` is valid syntax... do you have a debugger on? Maybe that is where it is getting captured.

Comment: I already solved it. It was just a session name. It contained a space, which apparently isn't supported by Safari and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a session name. It contained a space, which apparently isn't supported by Safari and IE.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where was the space in the session name and why? I may be having similiar issues

Comment: @Lars Jensen Hi it's been a while but could you explain what you mean. What fixes you did etc.. Thanks!